# Requested JSON Parse Error when sending two variables values using $.ajax

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

The code below is inside script of view.cshtml
All I want to achieve is parse the values MinDate and MaxDate into my controller. 
But I always get Requested JSON Parse Error. I used the variable MinDate and MaxDate in data {}
same error i even tried to pass the raw default MinDate and MaxDate into data {}
and I still got same error. What could the problem be?

```
// Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs
$('#FromDate').on("keyup change", function () {
    var MinDate =  $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", $("#FromDate").datepicker("getDate"));
    var MaxDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", $("#ToDate").datepicker("getDate"));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/CAACAllExpense/LEADFilter',
        data: { 'data1': "12-10-2019", 'data2': "14-10-2019" },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            $('#Error').html(msg);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: You might need to specify what kind of date picker you're using.

Comment: I just did some formatting and it looks like you have an extra comma at the end of the error.

Comment: Please where is the comma, I did not see it in the edit

Comment: 3rd-last line `},`.

Answer (score 0):

`data` needs to be a string:

```
data = JSON.stringify({ 'data1': "12-10-2019", 'data2': "14-10-2019" })
```

Comment: Actually, I think you only need this if method is POST.